# gdb : How to confirm that a breakpoint is set on a function?

Tags: gdb

I have set about 50 breakpoints in my project. How do I figure out if a breakpoint was set in a particular function? I don't want to use

```
info breakpoints
```

as it shows all of them. I just want to confirm if there is a breakpoint on this one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only approach I know for this is turning on logging, listing the breakpoints and turning it off. Then use *cat* and *grep* from within **gdb** to find your breakpoint by function name.

```
set logging file breaks.txt
set logging on
info break
set logging off
shell cat breaks.txt | grep function_name
```

Don't forget to delete the file when you change the breakpoint list because these commands will append logs to the existing file and you don't want that.

I know that someone can probably write a *gdb* script to automate this task, but this is the main idea.